# Chromium-based browser for Android with add-on-support

Tags: android, chrome

The up-to-date Chrome browser on my Android 4.x tablet [does not support addons](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/faq). ( Which appears to be on purpose to protect ad-revenue and business models if I am not mistaken. For that reason for anything *μblock/ABP/Ghostery* I can only use Firefox, which allows all of that...)

Since Chromium is at least basically/mostly open-source...

Are there any stable alternatives, meaning: **Chromium-based browsers with add-on support?**

(of common Chrome plugins, not something deeply excotic, following its own ‘standards’...

— or is that anyway impossible, because some add-on related stuff is closed source in Chrome?)

Comment: Not sure about the backends used – but be welcome to take a look at my list of [Android Web Browsers](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/network_webbrowser) to narrow down your search, while waiting for good answers ;)

Comment: why not just use Firefox?

Comment: I do use Firefox for precisely this reason, but for certain purposes (and certain plugins) it would be so much nicer to still have that choice.